# Mvc asp.net redirects to home controller after logging in though i have changed the default controller. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

[routeconfig.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipq6N.png)

Running the application brings me to my new default controller's index. But when I login successfully it redirects me to Home controller's index view. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look your AccountController Login method default returnUrl can be Home/Index

Comment: case SignInStatus.Success return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);                                              But the returnurl is the url of the page from which login request was made and the request was made through People/Index (new default controller)